# CSS Dropdown Menu Functionality Error In IE7,8 & 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a CSS dropdown menu that works perfectly in Mozilla/Chrome/Safari. However it is a bit iffy if `IE10` (but works) but does not work at all in `IE9`.

I have tried to figure out what is causing this as there are websites that use CSS dropdown menus that function perfectly in IE.

Please see here for fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xZuDC/

The images are as follows:

1. Normal Menu in chrome

   [image: Menu In Chrome]
2. Menu in IE

   [image: Menu In IE]

**List:**

```
<ul class="ulrRight">
    <li><a onclick="your_name">Your Account</a>
        <ul id="your_name">
            <li><a href="/index.php?f=mydetails">Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="/index.php?f=mypassword">Password</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You fiddle only displays a default `ul`, you may have forgot something.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>`   please declared a doctype

Comment: There was a syntax in fiddle. **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xZuDC/4/)**'s the one updated. Since the text is white, I also added dark background to the menu container.

Comment: Thats @matewka - but it still doesnt work like that in IE. Just its just a list as in the photo shown above

Comment: @JSpring I know that. I just wanted to make the fiddle more readible and usefull.

Comment: @matewka your fiddle works fine on IE8..

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes and as far as I can tell it works in IE9.

This was the only thing I found to cause the fiddle to not work, `<ul class="ulrRight">`  <--- had an extra r after ul

jsfiddle doesn't seem to work in IE 8 and under, at least in the console's browser view.

Here is the fiddle with the updates I made

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/xZuDC/5/)

I would suggest just writing this a little cleaner like so:

```
<div class="dropDown">
  <ul>
      <li>Your Account
          <ul>
             <li>Details</li>
              <li>Password</li>
          </ul> 
      </li>
      <li>Help
          <ul>
              <li>Support</li>
              <li>Contact Us</li>
              <li>Client FAQ's</li>
              <li>Haulier FAQ's</li>
          </ul>            
      </li>
      <li>Logout</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropDown {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: mediumSeaGreen;
}

.dropDown > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropDown > ul > li {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropDown > ul > li:hover {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropDown > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.dropDown > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[fiddle for code](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/XvQRH/)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work in IE 9 when I put it to use on the website altough it does work through jsFiddle. It pretty much looks the same as the photo i attached in my first post but not as padded :(